# Acess Parent-Cass members from a member-Calss

Tags: c++, class, parent, member

To make my question a little better to understand here is some code:

```
class parent{
    public:
    int number;
    string getUnit();
    myClass myMember;
}

class myClass{
    public:
    int counter;
    string getParentUnit();
}
```

Now I want my `getParentUnit()`to do something like

```
string myClass::getParentUnit(){
    retrun parent.getUnit();
}
```

I know I could modify `myClass` to take the `this` pointer of `parent` in the constructor and save it for later but I have several classes "inside" of each other like:

```
class a{
<...>
    b B;
<...>
}

class b{
<...>
    c C;
}

class c{
<...>
    d D;
<...>
}
```

and in class `d` I need to access the something from class `a`.

So I don't want to change around everything to have backwards references if there is a better way to do this.

Greetings
NIoSaT

Comment: Isn't `myClass` supposed to inherit `parent`?

Comment: change myClass to "class myClass : public parent" then just use "return getUnit();"

Comment: As your question say "Access parent class", i did not see any inheritance relationship. You should have inheritance in place to have parent - child relationship. Please edit the question to proper way so that we can share you better answer.

Comment: That was my Problem... I did not know the proper words to describe my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem: There is an application (corresponding to the object of class `a`), and then objects in lower level of abstraction need to access the application context (members of `a`).

Often people apply the easy, yet highly problematic solution of global variables, making `a` accessible to the entire application code. Beware of this: It means that `d` is not testable, because you have to set up the entire application in order for `d` to function. If the dependency is not affecting the behavior of `d`, but only adding marginal side effects such as a logger, then it might be acceptable, because you can still test the behavior of `d` without a logger.

The clean way to do this is for every object to explicitly get its dependencies either in the constructor or in setter functions. This requires more work now, but it creates maintainable code, because the API of each class explicitly says what the dependencies are. Also, every class can now be tested independently.

```
class A {
public:
  A(Params p) : b(p) {}
private:
  Params params;
  B b;
};

class B {
public:
  B(Params p) : C(c) {}
private:
  Params params;
  C c;
};

class C {
public:
  C(Params p) : params(p) {}
private:
  Params params;
};
```

I recommend to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0, where this is explained very nicely.

Comment: This seems like the only real way to do it, except for some wired pointer arithmetic to find stuff in the RAM, so I guess I will have to add all the backwards pointer, but thanks